# ASP.Net Onclick event doesn't work with ajaxcontroltoolkit

Tags: asp.net, events, ajaxcontroltoolkit, onclick

I designing a web application using vs2008 and c#.
I already have done many versions of it and all of them seems to be working fine.

Yesterday i decided to replace de vs calendar with a ajax calendar and to do so i used ajaxcontroltoolkit. The new calendar is also working fine.

But the buttons i have in my form stoped to work.

The onclick event just do nothing.
i've already change back to the older calendar and everything works ok.

The button calls a method on code behind.

So, any of you guys have a clue about what i'm doing wrong?
Is there other ways of doing this?

Tks in advance

Comment: Do you have any errors reported from the scripts in your browser?
Also you might want to make sure that the script manager is loaded at the top of the page.  Please post some code so that we can see what the page looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for yours answers

my problem is that i'm using this **onsubmit="return setHourglass();** on my form so the user know when the page is waiting for a response.

Something like this:

Bellow the script code

function setHourglass() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
        }

i removed that and is working ok, but i really don't know the motive for this behaviour :|